# How to generate a multi-file godbolt project from scratch?

Tags: c++, godbolt

So from the [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/pcrg7j/compiler_explorer_now_supports_multiple_file/), I got to https://godbolt.org/z/WseTsM8YG and I decided I'd try my hand at making a multi-file project on godbolt from scratch.  However, something seems to be wrong.  My project:  https://godbolt.org/z/7asGz3Wov

Seems that `main.cpp` can't see the `header.h` file for some reason.  I added each file separately, and they appear to be in the same directory as shown here:
[image: shows main.cpp and the project where it and header.h reside]

I even attempted to add the current directory to the include list (which shouldn't be necessary) with the `-I.` command line switch.  Not surprisingly, it didn't work.

My original `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(main.exe VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(main main.cpp source1.cpp source2.cpp)
```

I then changed to align with the reddit example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

#project(main.exe VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(main main.cpp source1.cpp source2.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main)
```

That didn't do anything either.

It would appear the files are not located in the same directory.  What magic am I missing to do that?

Comment: Thank you @joergbrech.  You should post this as an answer instead of a comment.  Yeah, I know now that my project doesn't compile as I didn't get a chance to debug. My header name isn't correct.  Works after fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler tab you have open does not use your Multifile CMake setup.

In the Tree View, you need to click on "Add new" and then "Execution only". This will trigger the execution of `cmake --build` with the given cmake options. It will also tell you all the other things that still need fixing (your code doesn't compile).

In addition, your target_link_libraries does nothing, since you don't specify any libraries to link to.

See here: godbolt.org/z/1Woeo6x9E